# Converting string into multiple sql columns in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

`INSERT INTO validation.alert_log select '123',1,'PLEASE CHECK','2023-09-22 13:39:18', regexp_substr('select ACQUIRE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,tx.receipt_id,receipt_item_id from incoming.RAW_tx_123 tx join  incoming.raw_recpt_123 recpt on tx.receipt_id = recpt.receipt_id','select ([\\s\\S=]*)',1, 1, 'e', 1)`
In the above code within regexp_substr we have 3 columns. These 3 column names comes as a single string but I want to convert as 3 separate columns so that I can insert 7 values into alert_log table.

I can convert this regexp_substr into Array but not sure how to extract individual column names and make the insertion statement.
Please note that I am using Javascript Stored procedure to create the above statement

How to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question, using editable text, with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve.